# what is async keyword and render() in react native ?what does it actually do

Tags: javascript, react-native, render

What is async keyword in react native?? 
I'm new to react native so can anybody help me with this thing :)
and I've actually tried to see if there some question on stack overflow but I haven't got anything!!

```
   export default class CameraExample extends React.Component {
        state = {
        hasCameraPermission: null,
        type: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
  };

   async componentDidMount() {
        const { status } = await 
        Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
        this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted' });
  }
```

Comment: it's a **simpler and more readable** syntax for executing **async operation** ... instead of using `then catch` ... and it's a javascript thing ... it's not something specific to ReactNative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) is a Javascript feature to work with [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), it's not so simple, please read about `Promises` before `async`.

The `render()` is the most important function in React as it tells your target (web, or native in your case) what to display on the screen. When using a Class component, you will need to `return` your view on the `render()` method. However, using functional components, the component itself is a "render()" method and will display what returns from him.

Answer (score 0):

```
   const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
   this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted' });
```

is an ES7-syntax equivalent of

```
Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA)
   .then(({ status }) => this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted' });
```